# Gql get all children of ancestor without the ancestor itself

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to build a forum like platform on GAE.

I must mention first: I'm a bit new to GAE.

I want to pull all replies to a specific post.
So far the structure looks like so:

```
- Forum
--- Post
----- Reply ( = Post with Post as a parent )
```

Replies are just posts with post as their parent(instead of the forum as a parent).

The problem begins when I try to pull out all of the replies, the returned results include the ancestor itself.

How can I achieve the same without the ancestor itself?(Might need to mention also that I searched for a solution but haven't found one)

**Edit:**

My query is like so:

```
replies = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1", post)
```

**Thanks!**

**Update:**

Well I've found a way:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 AND __key__ != :2", post, post.key())
```

just query and rule out the ancestor itself in the where clause!

Comment: remove it from the list?

Comment: I thought of that, but isn't there a way to get it without the ancestor?

Comment: @juxstapose and this rules out the option to know when the result bucket is count is 0.

Comment: can you explain why you need to store them in the same entity group? I can't imagine the referential integrity is vitally important between Forum/Post/Reply given the nature of the application. Just using `ReferenceProperty` without `parent` relationships woudl seem more sensible (unless I am misunderstanding something)

Comment: Shlomi: can you post the code that you are using to get those results? That would be a big help. Also, is this Python or Java?

Comment: @Shlomi, seeing the query you're running would be very helpful.

Comment: @Robert Kluin @Adam Crossland Well I did mention that I use Python. Someone removed the tag. I will edit and insert the query

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe Well, you are right, but as a message is a message, I guess I'm still thinking in relational db terminology instead of entities. it's like a tree forum, a parent of a post can be either a forum or another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution uses an inequality filter in the query. Inequality filters aren't supported by the underlying datastore, and are internally translated into two separate queries, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 AND __key__ < :2
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 AND __key__ > :2
```

Obviously, this is substantially less efficient. A much simpler and more efficient option is to simply fetch all results, then discard the one entity that you don't want.

Comment: sorry for the lack of knowledge, but how do you discard an item from this collection?

Comment: @Shlomi By using a list comprehension, for instance - [x for x in results where x.key() != foo].

Answer (score 2):

If you have the parent key you do not have to fetch the parent post entity.  If you have a string version of the parent post's key:

```
parent_post = db.Key(string_version_of_the_key)
replies = Post.all().ancestor(parent_post).fetch(num_to_fetch)
```

If you have the parent post's key id or name:

```
parent_post = db.Key.from_path('Post', id_or_key_name)
replies = Post.all().ancestor(parent_post).fetch(num_to_fetch)
```

See the docs on the [Key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html) class for more details.

Comment: And if I want to fetch all child posts?

Comment: @Shlomi Given the parent's key, id, or name this *will* select only the 'replies' (or child Post entities), without needing to fetch the parent entity.

Comment: First off, this doesn't work, it return san error, there is no ancestor method in the db.Model. Secondly when I use `Post.all().ancestor(parent_post)` works but still returns the post itself with the results

Comment: @Shlomi, yep -- the missing all() was a typo.  You are also right, the parent entity is returned in the results.

Comment: thanks anyways :), I think I've found a way! in query you can also rule the key in the where clause!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your code is in Python or not, but your query should look something like this:

`replies = Reply.ancestor(post).fetch(num_to_fetch)`

that will definitely not return `post` in your result set, as an entity can not be its own ancestor.